# Is there a search in page feature in OneNote in Windows 8?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

The standard search bar (Ctrl+F shortcut) only searches throughout the pages in a OneNote notebook.

Is there a way to search a large page for some text like standard Word search function?

Comment: Unless your content is text, a search feature, wouldn't find very much unless you already ran it through OCR

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+E will search all your notebooks. However, your question is a bit confusing, and I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.